# Mut, Tapferkeit, Sicherheit, Porzellankiste?

Tags: etymology, expression

Im Ausdruck:

> Vorsicht ist die Mutter der Porzellankiste

(er könnte indirekt von [Shakespeare kommen](http://www.q-world.de/service/keywords/quizfragen-zum-thema/keywords/P/16/3/Porzellankiste/no_cache.html) aber ich finde diesen Artikel nicht schlüssig)

Warum hat die Porzellankiste Tapferkeit oder Mut ersetzt?

Was ist die Geschichte dieser verblüffenden Redensart?

(NB: Die Franzosen haben einen ähnlichen Ausdruck: *Prudence est mère de Sureté*, Vorsicht ist die Mutter der Sicherheit).

Comment: Hier wird auch Shakespeare angeführt, auch wenn die Erläuterung etwas wirr ist: http://www.eukomm.de/vorsicht-ist-die-mutter-der-porzellankiste/

Comment: @ladybug : Danke. Er stellt wichtigen genealogischen Fragen :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Irgendwo](http://bauernregeln.aio-world.net/sprichwoerter_erklaert_41083431.html) fand ich folgende Erklärung:

> Vorsicht ist die Mutter der Porzellankiste
>
> Natürlich ist es wieder ein Spruch aus alten Zeiten. Nämlich aus den Zeiten, wo es noch das "gute Porzellan" gab, das nur zu festlichen Gelegenheiten genutzt wurde. Und da dieses Porzellan so wertvoll (teuer) war, ging die Mutter besonders vorsichtig beim Auspacken und Gebrauch damit um.
> Denn ursprünglich hieß der Spruch einmal "Vorsichtig ist die Mutter IN der Porzellankiste"!

---

Verschiedene Quellen, auch der Duden, legen eine mögliche Verwandtschaft mit dem älteren Ausspruch "Vorsicht ist die Mutter der Weisheit" nahe, während die Variante mit der Porzellankiste als umgangssprachlich/scherzhaft beschrieben wird. Bei Google zeigt sich eine Verbreitung erst in den Dreißigern; erst in den Achtzigern/Neunzigern zeigt sich eine Verdrängung. Hier ist jedoch zu beachten, dass das komplette Zitat aus sechs Wörtern besteht und daher nicht vollständig abgebildet werden kann; daher ist dieses Diagramm spekulativ.

Möglicherweise zeigt insbesondere der hintere Teil (ab 1980) aber tatsächlich eine Ableitung der Porzellankiste aus der Weisheit (scherzhafte Abwandlung einer Redewendung, wie öfter geschehen), weil hier die Kurven gegenläufig sind.

[image]

Comment: IN oder MIT der Porzellankiste?

Comment: *In* der Porzellankiste? "Mutter! komm da raus, wir wissen dass Du da drin bist! Und bring den Elephanten mit!"

Comment: Ich hab' an anderer Stelle auch schon gelegentlich gelesen, dass einige Leute "in der Porzellankiste" sagen. Beim Hantieren in der Kiste ist vielleicht gemeint - heute hat man da vielleicht einen Pappkarton, aber früher war das ja mitunter schon eine große Holzkiste.

Answer (score 1):

Die Erklärung von OregonGhost scheint mir zu weit her geholt (ich wage auch an der Quelle zu zweifeln). Mir leuchtet dieses Sprichwort in ganz direkter Weise ein. Die Mutter ist hier allegorisch gemeint.

Die Mutter ist notwendig für das Überleben der Kinder.
Die Vorsicht ist notwendig für das Überleben des Porzellans.

Also nimmt die Vorsicht die Mutterrolle ein, wenn es um Porzellan geht.

Comment: Es ist nicht notwendig, in deiner Antwort meine explizit anzuzweifeln; das wäre besser als Kommentar zu meiner Antwort aufgehoben, den man dann auch prima einzeln aufwerten könnte. Aber das nur am Rande. Deine Antwort klingt nicht unschlüssig, wenngleich spekulativ (ich konnte ebensowenig Belege dafür finden wie für die von mir zitierte These). Die Variante "Vorsicht ist die Mutter der Weisheit", die mir bei den Recherchen aufgefallen ist (und auf die ich jetzt in meiner Antwort im zweiten Teil eingehe) lässt sich so allerdings nicht erklären. Ist aber ohnehin alles spekulativ :)